# Changing the default style of Android Action Bar Tab header

Tags: android-actionbar, android, android-tabs

I have implemented tabs in Android using `ViewPager` and `ActionBar`. The tabs work without any issue and I have got the default ActionBar tab headers as shown in following image.
[image: Default tab headers]

But I want to change the headers as shown in following image. It would be really nice if someone could help me on this.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try this ActionBar generator [Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/)

or You can define the color of the ActionBar by creating a custom Style:

go and edit the

> res/values/styles.xml

file of your Android project.

here is an example :

```
<resources>
    <style name="MyCustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">ANY_HEX_COLOR_CODE</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Then set "MyCustomTheme" as the Theme of your Activity that contains the ActionBar.

You can also set a color for the ActionBar like this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.RED)); // set your desired color
```

EDIT

in order to make your own indicator you need to make it with photoshop or gimp and create it as a 9patch drawable and then declare it like this where tab_unselected_holo is your own indicator png

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <!-- Non focused states -->
        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_holo" />
        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_holo" />

        <!-- Focused states -->
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_holo" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_holo" />

        <!-- Pressed -->
        <!--    Non focused states -->
        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_holo" />
        <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_holo" />

        <!--    Focused states -->
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_focused_holo" />
        <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_focused_holo" />
    </selector>
```

then add a style xml file like this

```
 <style name="Widget.Holo.TabWidget" parent="Widget.TabWidget">
        <item name="android:tabStripLeft">@null</item>
        <item name="android:tabStripRight">@null</item>
        <item name="android:tabStripEnabled">false</item>
        <item name="android:divider">?android:attr/dividerVertical</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
        <item name="android:dividerPadding">8dip</item>
        <item name="android:measureWithLargestChild">true</item>
        <item name="android:tabLayout">@android:layout/tab_indicator_holo</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I want to put the indicator arrow shown in the second image. Color is not a problem.